How to structure rich-content form in modal view
What is the best approach to organize/structure modal forms?
I used to have this form in single page but the user want it in modal view. the issue here is that we might have more features in the future and requires more input fields to be added in the form.
I would love to hear your thoughts on this
Thank you


Do you have certain sections dependent on others?

Knowing that a modal should have immediate and easily perceived information, a form breaks with this premise, so it would try to reduce the amount of information contained to the maximum.
For example, dividing the modal into sections using tabs and, if necessary, a summary with the added data:

